# Is it possible to use a 16 color theme in gnome-terminal?

Tags: command-line, gnome, color-scheme, gnome-terminal

Has anyone been able to do this successfully? As far as I can tell this is very difficult because gnome-terminal lacks an option to disable "use bright as bold". Which means that:

```
$ echo "\e[1;31mred"  # bold, color #1 (red)
```

and

```
$ echo "\e[31mred"  # no bold, color #1 (red)
```

will use different colors (the former will actually use color #9, 'bright red'), whereas 16 color themes depend on this *not* happening.

You can get around it by doing:

```
$ echo "\e[1;38;5;1mred"
```

which will display bold text with color #1, not color #9, but many existing apps don't do this, and rely on `"\e[1;31mred"` being red.

Barring modifying all terminal applications that use color to use the 38 code method, is there any way to get gnome-terminal to work w/ these themes?

Answer (score 0):

Answering this ancient question, just for the record:

In 2018 gnome-terminal added the option you were looking for, it's called "Show bold text in bright colors" in its Preferences window.

Subsequently in 2019 it even made it disabled by default, which is your preferred behavior.

The option to revert to the old behavior is still there and will likely remain for a very long time.